# JWT add different subject depending on the data in the body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, jose4j

I've been asked to generate a token depending on the username that is asking for it. Now I'm creating a token just with a single subject but I don't know how to change the subject dinamically before creating the token depending on the body of the request.

This is what I've done so far to generate a token with a single subject:
The service class:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtService {

    @Value("${issuer}")
    private String issuer;
    @Value("${kid}")
    private String keyId;
    @Value("#{'${audience}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> audiences;
    @Value("#{'${subject}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> subject;

    private final JwtKeyProvider jwtKeyProvider;

    public String generateToken() throws JoseException {
       
        JwtClaims claims = new JwtClaims();
        claims.setIssuer(issuer);
        claims.setAudience(Lists.newArrayList(audiences));
        claims.setExpirationTimeMinutesInTheFuture(60);
        claims.setJwtId(keyId);
        claims.setIssuedAtToNow();
        claims.setNotBeforeMinutesInThePast(0);
        claims.setSubject(subject);
     
        JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();

        jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());

        jws.setHeader("typ", "JWT");

        jws.setKey(jwtKeyProvider.getPrivateKey());
        jws.setKeyIdHeaderValue(keyId);
        jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(AlgorithmIdentifiers.RSA_USING_SHA256);
        
        String jwt = jws.getCompactSerialization();
        return jwt;
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JWTController {

    private final JwtService jwtService;

    @PostMapping("/getToken")
    public ResponseEntity getJwt(@RequestBody JwtRequest request) throws JoseException {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(
                    JwtResponse.builder()
                            .token(jwtService.generateToken())
                            .build()
            );
    }
}
```

I could do it doing like this:

```
 @PostMapping("/getToken")
        public ResponseEntity getJwt(@RequestBody JwtRequest request) throws JoseException {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(
                        JwtResponse.builder()
                                .token(jwtService.generateToken(request.getUsername()))
                                .build()
                );
        }
    }
```

But I don't want to send any parameters in the generateToken function as I would have to change a lot of code then.

To resume I want to assign to the subject the value of the username that is sent in the body. So is there a way in the JwtService class to receive that username and set as the subject after?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WHy do you want a list in the subject?

Comment: I have multiple username that can create token. These usernames are also the subjects of the token, so at the end I want to reflect the value of that subject depending on the value of the username

Comment: just pass in username from the request into your function and set it as the subject? i dont see the problem here

Comment: WHere should I set this? Is not clear for me

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put whitelist=user1,user2 in your application.properties, because sometimes names might trigger as system variables (for example username does)

Then in JWTController you need to check if not user equals, but contains in list

```java
    @Value("#{'${whitelist}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> whitelist;

    @PostMapping("/getToken")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getJwt(@RequestBody JwtRequest request) throws JoseException {
        if(whitelist.contains(request.username())) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(
                    JwtResponse.builder()
                            .token(jwtService.generateToken(request.username()))
                            .build()
            );
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Invalid username");
        }
    }
```

In your JWTService you need to set JWT Subject to username which passed through whitelist

```java
claims.setSubject(username);
```

And finally you need to do JSON request to server

```json
{
    "username": "user2"
}
```

Comment: this code is very dangerous as with this code anyone can set any value as the subject in the token. Do not use this code.

Comment: That's why Im using a List of subjects that are the same as the username, so If the username pass in the body belongs to that list, it has to generate the token with that valid username/subject

Comment: @Toerktumlare I've just noticed that there's no password check. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't have a password. Im creating the token from a private key

Comment: @DiegoMG I don't really understand how it supposed to work

Comment: the person asking is not very clear in his question, but what it looks like is that he has a defined "whitelist" of users that can be set as subject. So what he wants is that the username should be checked against this list, if and only if the user is in that list it should be set as subject.

Comment: Yes that's exaclty what I need!

Comment: I've update the Q, hope its clearer now!

Comment: @DiegoMG can you please include your application.properties or where you have this list to test it

Comment: @Georglider I've updated the question. At the end you'll find the values of the app.prop

Comment: @Georglider Is there a way to avoid passing as a parameter that username in JwtService?

Comment: @DiegoMG Well, I think you could try generating something random as username value